# interval between 3 dates, ifelse with 3 options

Tags: r

```
d <- wrapr::build_frame( "ID" , "DATE", "DATE2","DATE3" | 1 , "2001-01-01" , "2004-01-01","NA"| 2 , "2001-01-01" , "NA","2003-02-02" | 3 , "2001-01-01" , "NA","NA")

  ID       DATE      DATE2      DATE3
1  1 2001-01-01 2004-01-01         NA
2  2 2001-01-01         NA 2003-02-02
3  3 2001-01-01         NA         NA
```

I want to calculate days between DATE and DATE2, if DATE2 is NA then difference between DATE and DATE3. If both DATE2 and DATE3 is NA. Then difference between fixed date (2018-12-12) and DATE.

Anyone eager to help? :)
Best H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can use a combination of `mutate` and `case_when`:

First we covert the columns to date format and then we calculate the difference case by case.

```
library(dplyr)
fixed_date <- as.Date('2018-12-12', format = '%Y-%m-%d')

d %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = c('DATE','DATE2','DATE3'), .funs = as.Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d') %>% 
  mutate(Date_diff = case_when(!is.na(DATE2) & is.na(DATE3) ~ abs(DATE - DATE2),
                               !is.na(DATE3) & is.na(DATE2) ~ abs(DATE - DATE3), 
                               TRUE~abs(DATE - fixed_date)))
```

Comment: I think I left an extra trailing ")" and might want to change the message body to say mutate and case_when rather than ifelse

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Does look cleaner. Although not sure whether OP was looking for an `ifelse` answer. Nevertheless this does the job better.

Comment: Thanks alot:) Ifelse wasn’t required